# How can I create PHP file in javaweb in netbeans

Tags: php, html, netbeans, java-web-start

I want to create a PHP file in NetBeans and include it with my (javaWeb) project?

Answer (score 0):

Simply just right click on the folder in which you want to create a new php file. Then select php file. If you can't see any php file option just select `other` and select php then select file types.

Comment: i can't find it there :(